# reflow content when column changes size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need a little help. I have been struggling with this one for a couple of days.

I am toggling columns using the method I found below below.

[Bootstrap toggle left column in a two column row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826097/bootstrap-toggle-left-column-in-a-two-column-row)

In my larger column (Col1) that shrinks when I expose the right column (col2), I would like my two columns (col1, col1 and col1, col2) to adjust to single column. I am beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out. I am sure it is something painfully obvious that I will feel silly when someone show the solution.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="list-col" class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 item">
          Col1, col1
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 item">
          Col1, col2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map-col" class="col-xs-0">COL 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/td234/qu7j21pm/1/

Thanks for any and all help!

Thom

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zapuew54/

Comment: YES, exactly. Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to toggle the classes on the `col-xs-6` columns to be `col-xs-12`.

`$('.item').toggleClass('col-xs-12 col-xs-6');`